How to join in alerts?
I'm trying to set alerts whenever there is a pod restart.
As part of this alert it will be nice to display the restart reason as well.
I tried the following:
First, I tried the inner join and join by labels. But both the queries didn't work.
(changes(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{namespace="sandbox"}[30m]) > 0)
*
(kube_pod_container_status_last_terminated_reason{namespace="sandbox"} == 1)

(changes(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{namespace="sandbox"}[30m]) > 0
 * on(pod)
 group_left(container)
 kube_pod_container_status_last_terminated_reason{namespace="sandbox"} == 1
)

Using the similar queries I created a dashboard and applied Outer "join by field" transformation and that works fine. But in alerts I tried using + instead of * and that didn't work either.

One of the mistakes in the latter query is lack of parentheses around comparison: multiplication has higher priority than > or ==. Regarding labels - it's unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve.
